# Scrape the HTML from a webpage? - VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to make a Windows Desktop app that will go to a specified site and take the HTML from that site. I have found many examples to do this, but for some reason it doesn't work on classic Google Sites pages. The program needs to find simple text in the body of a Google Sites page. It doesn't display the same code that Google Chrome shows when you "view page source". What's wrong?

```
Public Sub Scrape(strURL)
    Try

        Dim wrResponse As WebResponse
        Dim wrRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)

        textScrape = "Extracting..." & Environment.NewLine

        wrResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse()

        Using sr As New StreamReader(wrResponse.GetResponseStream())
            strOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
            ' Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close()
        End Using

        textScrape = strOutput

        'Formatting Techniques

        ' Remove Doctype ( HTML 5 )
        strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<!(.|\s)*?>", "")

        ' Remove HTML Tags
        ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>", "")

        ' Remove HTML Comments
        ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<!--(.|\s)*?-->", "")

        ' Remove Script Tags
        ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<script.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        ' Remove Stylesheets
        ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<style.*?</style>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        scrapeFormatted = strOutput 'write Formatted Output To Separate TB

        Form2.Show()

    Catch ex As Exception

        ErrorMsg("", "")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. For anyone who is looking for info on this, the code above works perfectly.
Be sure that you insert the proper link into the "strURL" variable. That was a very stupid mistake on my part.

```
Public Sub Scrape(strURL)
Try

    Dim wrResponse As WebResponse
    Dim wrRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)

    textScrape = "Extracting..." & Environment.NewLine

    wrResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse()

    Using sr As New StreamReader(wrResponse.GetResponseStream())
        strOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
        ' Close and clean up the StreamReader
        sr.Close()
    End Using

    textScrape = strOutput

    'Formatting Techniques

    ' Remove Doctype ( HTML 5 )
    strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<!(.|\s)*?>", "")

    ' Remove HTML Tags
    ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>", "")

    ' Remove HTML Comments
    ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<!--(.|\s)*?-->", "")

    ' Remove Script Tags
    ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<script.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    ' Remove Stylesheets
    ' strOutput = Regex.Replace(strOutput, "<style.*?</style>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    scrapeFormatted = strOutput 'write Formatted Output To Separate TB

    Form2.Show()

Catch ex As Exception

    ErrorMsg("", "")

End Try
```

End Sub